# No hint path defined for [mail]

Tags: laravel

so i was trying to send a mail with a pdf attachment but i get this error No hint path defined for [mail].

here is my buld function syntax

```
public function build()
    {
        $pdf = $this->pdf;
        return $this->subject("Transaction Request")
            ->from('finance@vcass.org')
            ->attachData($pdf, 'transaction.pdf', [
                'mime' => 'application/pdf'
            ])
            ->markdown('emails.usersingle', ['transaction' => $this->transaction]);
    }
```

and here is my controller code

```
public function sendtransaction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $id = $data['id'];
        $transaction = Transaction::find($id);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('emails.usersingle', compact('transaction'));

        $pdf = $pdf->output();

        try {

            Mail::to($data['email'])->send(new MailTransaction($transaction, $pdf));




            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'transaction sent to mail, check your mail');
        } catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {

            return redirect()->back()->with('warning', 'Sorry mail couldnt be sent, please try again');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            dd($e);
        }
    }
```

please I need help on this fast!

Comment: fast? How fast?

Comment: lolzz, please just help if you have a solution